# Load x Numbers from one line python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying make a program which accepts some numbers written in one line in python, but it does not work the way I expect it to.
I get the input with:

```
x = int(input())
```

and then try to build a list:

```
list = []
for i in range(x):
    list.append(int(input()))
```

But this only works if I input the numbers one after another.
I want to parse an input line like this

```
1 2 3
```

into a list of numbers.

Comment: please note that `list` is a very bad variable name for a list because you shadow the built-in list.

Comment: thanks i will edit it and also keep it in mind

Answer (score 4):

You can simply split your input by whitespace.

```
>>> inp = input()
1 2 3 4
>>> inp.split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

This will give you a list of your numbers as strings. To convert them to actual integers, you could use map:

```
>>> list(map(int, inp.split()))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Using `list` is redundant here, as `split` will already produce a list.

Comment: @vesche nope, this question is about Python3 where `map` will return a map object. It has nothing to do with `split` returning a list.

Comment: Using a list comprehension is considered more Pythonic than using `map` (see e.g. GvR comment on PEP 279). But in either case I would recomment using a function with some error checking instead of a plain `int()`

Answer (score 1):

Adding some security measure won't hurt as well, to make sure user entered a digit not something else:

```
inp = input('Enter Numbers:')

lst = [int(i) for i in inp.split() if i.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `split` method of strings, and a list comprehension:

```
num_str = input("Enter number string: ")
num_list = [int(i) for i in num_str.split()]
```

If `num_str` is: `"3 4 6 5 6"`

`num_list` will be: `[3, 4, 6, 5, 6]`

**More info:**

`str.split` info from the docs:

> Docstring: S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the delimiter
>   string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done. If
>   sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator
>   and empty strings are removed from the result. Type:
>   method_descriptor

list comprehensions:

http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Python-List-Comprehension

http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Answer (score -1):

```
mylist = []
uservals = input("enter some numbers: ")
for i in uservals.split():
    mylist.append(int(i))
```